# javascript to cocoa with variable args

Tags: javascript, cocoa, webview

I've got an objectiveC class who's methods I can invoke from javascript vai webscriptobject. However, I'd like to call my function from javascript providing a variable number of parameters.  For example,

myclass.myfunction(arg1, arg2, arg3 ....) where in the objectiveC side the function isn't limited to a specific number of arguments. I guess like using varargs.

Anyone does something like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my specific issue, i ended up implementing the following in my scriptobject. It lets me string compare against the function name and use the passed in array. Ideally should do some type checking on the arguments in the array...

```
(id)invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript:(NSString *)name withArguments:(NSArray *)args
{
//NSLog(@" debug WABridge invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScrip dump name: %@", name);
//NSLog(@" debug WABridge invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript args:  %@", args);

if ([name isEqualToString:@"javascriptToCWithArgs"]) 
{

    std::vector<std::wstring> dataArray;
    dataArray.reserve([args count]);

    for (id object in args) {
        std::wstring valAsWstring = NSStringToStringW(object);
        //place into vector
        dataArray.push_back(valAsWstring);
    }

            //callback into my code
    if (m_pWebView!= nil)
    {
        m_pWebView->m_pObjectiveCWebViewWrapper->getWebViewListener()->onMessageFromPageWithArgs(dataArray);
    }

}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Bridge undefined/unsupported function");
}



return nil;
}
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer as it actually answers the question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSNumber *) addValues:(int) count, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);

    NSNumber *value;

    double retval;

    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
    value = va_arg(args, NSNumber *);

    retval += [value doubleValue];

    }

    va_end(args);
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:retval];
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine as a generic function. I ended up solving my specific problem by implementing the following: - (id)invokeUndefinedMethodFromWebScript:(NSString *)name withArguments:(NSArray *)args

Comment: The method in this answer is not usable from JavaScript.